# filtar los feed que contenga un hashtag similar usando django-taggi

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework

Se tiene la librería django-taggi la cual hace relacion al feed de los usuario necesito generar el filtro por tags segun la libreria en un ejemplo de la documentacion se hace de esta manera.

```
Food.objects.filter(tags__name__in=["delicious"])
[<Food: apple>, <Food: pear>, <Food: plum>]
```

Modelo Feed:

```
    class Feed(UUIDModel, TimeStampedModel, mongo_models.Model, TaggitManager):
    #Demas campos

    class TaggitManager:
        hashtags = TaggableManager(through=UUIDTaggedItem)
    
        class Meta:
            abstract = True

    class UUIDTaggedItem(GenericUUIDTaggedItemBase, TaggedItemBase):
        pass
```

En el viewset del

```
@extend_schema(description="", tags=["feed"])
class FeedViewSet(LPCDRModelViewSet):
    def _check_required_param(self, param_name):
        param_value = self.request.query_params.get(param_name)
        if not param_value:
            return exceptions.ValidationError(
                 {"error": f"params {param_name} is required"}
           )
        return None
    
    def get_queryset(self):  
        if self.action == "feed_hashtag_list":
          error = self._check_required_param("hashtag")
          if not error:
             return Feed.objects.filter(hashtags__name__in=["demo", "red"])
```

Al querer consultar o filtrar por un tags nos genera el siguiente error:

`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'hashtags' into field. Choices are: background, background_id, blocked, can_audio, can_be_shared_inside, can_be_shared_outside, can_commentary, can_download, can_duos, can_paste_video, comment_feeds, content, count_shared, created, draft, event, exclusive_adult_content, feed_event, feed_private, feed_type, finish_poll, friends_concrete, friends_concrete_id, friends_except, friends_except_id, id, is_announcement, link, link_external, mediafeed, modified, near, parent, parent_duos, parent_duos_feed, parent_duos_id, parent_feed, parent_id, programed, publish, questionfeed, reactions, reactions_feed_relation, reactions_id, special_announcement, sponsors, sponsors_id, state, state_id, time_to_programed, user, user_id, user_tags, user_tags_id`

Answer (score 0):

Para quien le pueda interesar aqui la respuesta a mi propia pregunta espero les pueda servir aquellos que tengan el mismo problema que el mío

```
if self.action == "hashtag_list":
            error = self._check_required_param("hashtags__name")
            if not error:
                tag__name = self.request.query_params.get("hashtags__name")
                # Objeto ContentType correspondiente al modelo Feed. ContentType
                content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Feed)
                # Relación through entre los modelos Feed y Hashtag.
                # Se filtra la consulta para obtener los registros que coinciden
                # con el nombre del hashtag (tag__name) y el tipo de contenido (content_type) obtenidos anteriormente
                # El resultado se asigna a la variable queryset.
                queryset = Feed.hashtags.through.objects.filter(
                    tag__name=tag__name,
                    content_type=content_type,
                )
                # una lista de los valores de la columna "object_id" de los registros en el queryset.
                # Estos valores corresponden a los IDs de los feeds relacionados con los hashtags buscados.
                # Los valores se almacenan en la variable feed_ids.
                feed_ids = queryset.values_list("object_id", flat=True)
                # Serializamos los UUIDs a strings
                feed_ids = [str(id) for id in feed_ids]
                # Deserializamos los UUIDs a partir de cadenas
                feed_ids = [UUID(id) for id in feed_ids]
                # filtramos las coincidencias para obtener los registros cuyos IDs están en la lista feed_ids.
                feed = Feed.objects.filter(
                    id__in=feed_ids,
                    feed_type__in=["videos", "streaming", "challenge", "images"],
                )
                # Obtener el número de reacciones para cada feed
                feed_with_reactions = feed.annotate(
                    num_reactions=Count("reactions__id")
                )

                # Ordenar la lista de tuplas (feed, num_reactions) por el número de reacciones descendente
                filter_by = self.request.query_params.get(
                    "filter_by"
                )  # Parámetro para especificar el tipo de clasificación
                if filter_by == "recent":
                    sorted_feeds = feed.order_by("-created")
                elif filter_by == "popular":
                    sorted_feeds = feed_with_reactions.order_by("-num_reactions")
                else:
                    sorted_feeds = feed_with_reactions  # Sin clasificación específica

                # Obtener la lista final de feeds ordenados
                sorted_feed_ids = [feed.id for feed in sorted_feeds]
                sorted_feed = sorted(feed, key=lambda x: sorted_feed_ids.index(x.id))

                return sorted_feed
```